# Parameters not replacing properly in NpgsqlCommand

Tags: c#, .net, npgsql

I'm trying to replace parameters in a string to execute in an Npgsql query.

The problem is, when it replaces the parameter by its value in the string it adds unnecessary parentheses and so the query returns an error.

`NAME_SCHEMA_DB` and `NAME_ADMIN_DB` are string constants and
`ExecuteCommand` just takes an `NpgsqlCommand` and executes it.

This is my code:

```
String qdropSchema = @"DROP SCHEMA IF EXISTS @name_schem CASCADE";
String qCreateSchema = @"CREATE SCHEMA @name_schem AUTHORIZATION @name_admin";


DbCommand commandeDrop = new NpgsqlCommand(qdropSchema);
commandDrop.Parameters.Add(new NpgsqlParameter("@name_schem", NAME_SCHEMA_DB));

DbCommand commandCreate = new NpgsqlCommand(qCreateSchema);
commandCreate.Parameters.Add(new NpgsqlParameter("@name_schem", NAME_SCHEMA_DB));
commandCreate.Parameters.Add(new NpgsqlParameter("@name_admin", NAME_ADMIN_DB));


ExecuteCommand(commandDrop);
ExecuteCommand(commandCreate);
```

This is what the SQL query it tries to run when it reaches `ExecuteCommand(commandDrop)`

> DROP SCHEMA IF EXISTS (('test_schemaName')) CASCADE;

I 'm not sure why it adds the extra parentheses and single quotes. Normally, I'd want the query it runs to be

> DROP SCHEMA IF EXISTS test_schemaName CASCADE;

Comment: Because its a string, the parameter system is surrounding it in quotes. Parameters aren't really meant to specify tables or schemas. Is the schema name entered by a user?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SQL parameters are generally only valid for *values* (e.g. the values of fields) - not field names and table names etc. While it's annoying, you'll probably need to embed these names directly into the SQL.

You should be *very* careful doing that, of course - anywhere that it *might* be from user input, you should use a whitelist of some form.